# CreateReply is returning a 500 error

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I just tried this request according to the documentation [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/message_createreplyall)
The message ID in this URL is the `id` of an email that I just retrieved from `GET /me/messages`

```http
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/{id}/createReplyAll
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXSiOBJiV1QiLCJub25jZSI6Ik{....}
```

This is what comes back:

```json
"error": {
    "code": "InternalServerError",
    "message": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",
    "innerError": {
        "request-id": "a4c28622-0914-44da-8e67-6eb7ee59dc84",
        "date": "2017-10-09T19:07:00"
    }
}
```

I'm left to guess whether this is

1. A bad request (the `500` error doesn't seem to imply that)
2. This type of email is special and cannot be accessed or replied to for some reason (?) or
3. I found a bug and this is my bug report.

The same happens for `/createReply` endpoint as well

Answer (score 1):

I just reproduced this as well. Remove the `Content-Type` header to fix this. It seems the server is running into a bad error case when you say there's JSON in the body, but the body is empty :). This is definitely a bug in that we should never return a 500.

And I see that the Graph docs say that the header is required, even though there's no body. That seems like a doc bug to me.

I'll report up to the right folks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks; that header had been left in there as an oversight. FYI I removed the header in the 3 topics for createForward, createReply, and createReplyAll in v1.0 of Microsoft Graph. The updates will be live within 24 hours.